# Every open subset of $\mathbb{C}$ is countable union of compact subsets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have to show that every open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{C}$ is a countable union of compact subsets $\{K_j\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$  of $\Omega$ such that $K_j \subset \operatorname{int} K_{j+1}$ and $\cup_{j=1}^\infty K_j = \Omega$.

My thoughts: I know every open subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$ (and therefore $\mathbb{C}$ ) can be written as a union of open discs with rational center and radii. Enumerating them as $\{B_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ maybe can try taking their closure and defining $K_j = \cup_{i=1}^j \bar{B_i}$. But I don't think $K_j \subset \operatorname{int} K_{j+1}$ with this construction.

I would appreciate some help with this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For an open set $U$ of $\Bbb R^2$ consider the set $$[-n,n]^2\bigcap\bigg\{x\in\Bbb R^2:d(x,\Bbb R^2-U)\geq \frac{1}{n}\bigg\}.$$

Here, $$d(x,\Bbb R^2-U)=\inf\big\{||x-z||:z\in\Bbb R^2-U\big\}$$

Comment: Got it, thanks! Just a small doubt, since the set on the right is definitely closed, do we need the intersection with the square just so that it is bounded?

Comment: Yes, you are right, a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint. Try showing that every open disc can be written as the countable union of compact sets, and then think about diagonalisation together with the property you already know.